# Can you declare an array type of specific length in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Can this be written more compactly?

```
export type Type = 
  [number] | 
  [number, number] | 
  [number, number, number] | 
  [number, number, number, number];
```

Something like

```
export type Type = number[1, 4];
```

Comment: It is possible but it have recursion limit.

Comment: `number[] & {length: 1|2|3|4}` - nah that won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it a little more compact by using [tuples with optional elements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#optional-elements-in-tuple-types):

```
type OneToFourNumbers = [number, number?, number?, number?]
type Len = OneToFourNumbers["length"] // 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
```

This isn't 100% the same as your `Type`, since it accepts `undefined` elements (at least until something like [microsoft/TypeScript#43947](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/43947) is merged), but it's reasonably close.

---

If you want to do it programmatically and you don't plan to use tuples longer than about 20 elements, you can use [recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) on [variadic tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types):

```
type TupleLength<V, F extends number, T extends number, O extends any[] = []>
  = F extends O['length'] ? (
    T extends O['length'] ? O : TupleLength<V, F, T, O | [...O, V]>
  ) : TupleLength<V, F, T, [...O, V]>

type Type = TupleLength<number, 1, 4>;
/* type Type = [number] | [number, number] |
[number, number, number] | [number, number, number, number] */
```

Of course this is only "more compact" if you treat `TupleLength` as a [utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) that you hide in a library somewhere; if you're only going to use it once, the manual version is better.  And even if you use it a few times, you might still want to use the manual version because it's more understandable to TypeScript non-experts.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghgOwK5wDYBVzQLwFgBQUUA2sgLYBGEATgLpQA+BRpSlNANFOVXY8yR6dubXlyF8mhQaOETxs6gvZ0A3AQKhIUAPIII6APYAxQ0moA5RQGco2GSuW8A-E5quRK57U1YoADTtdfSNTcysVa2IAIlQIBABzYAALaPoAenSoAEZGKAAmPIBmPIAWDXxfbXQkMDiAGXik5IAeADUuYygIAA9geIATW3kodG6+weHFLh1x-oQhqEQQYnp7VYA+AXsu3vnFnWIAcjjElKP6ZygACgEiMb3J3WPT5ouoK9mALlHahqaUu1Olx0DM8sQAHRQnRcNq0LbSACUUB+NTqEEaZ1aHSgxhBXEh0Nh8IqWmgmG09jR-yxLRG2S4pQ26nw6QAVFAyaM-OsJPQGA4xJ5ePyCKxHMK5Ip+YKpRKRnyoGz0kA)

Answer (score 0):

A little bit more compact version:

```
export type Type = [number, number?, number?, number?];
```